# Raphael JS, Add text on connected line of griffle

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I tried to add text on middle of connected line in griffle with following the line function but it's so hard to me.

If anybody have solution for this issue, please answer.

Thank you.

```
Source Code: http://jsfiddle.net/A4JyM/
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A4JyM/) : I want 'Connection One', 'Bid Endpoints' like these on this page.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: actually like this. http://jsfiddle.net/A4JyM/

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? _(can you draw a picture and include it in your original question?)_

Comment: Please visit a http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/jquery.html and you can see 'Connection One' and 'big endpoint' texts on connection line. I want like this.